# How to create procedural gradient mosaic pattern

Tags: procedural

How can I combine a gradient and Voronoi (0 randomness) texture to create a gradient mosaic tile effect? Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which kind of result do you want to achieve (as it is probably not the last image you have included)?

Comment: The last image is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

That can be this:

[image]

The value node indicate the scale (20 here).

1 over this scale is the value we want to snap the cells to. But the coordinates are before shifted half of it in order to adapt to the voronoi texture.

For the gradient: it is compared to a white noise texture in order to have a progressive color over the randomness.

Last, the voronoi screens the grid in order to have the white separations around the cells.

Comment: good ol' nodes magic is what i'm here for :))